# How can I dynamically change kendo.mobile.Application's loading property?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am developing a mobile web app using Kendo UI Mobile. Whenever we make any AJAX calls, or our `DataSource`s make them we call `app.startLoading()` to show the loading icon to the user. This works very well.

However, depending on the context in which the call is made we would like to change the text that is displayed along with the loading icon. I know you can define this when I create the `kendo.mobile.Application` instance. How can I change it afterwards?

The [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/application) does not suggest a way to do this, and a browse of the source code did not help me either. Is this really not possible?

**EDIT:** This is using Kendo UI Mobile v.2012.3.1114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually make a "utility" function to do this:

```
    var _kendoApp = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {});

    var showLoading = function (message) {
        _kendoApp.loading = "<h1>" + (message ? message : "Loading...") + "</h1>";
        _kendoApp.showLoading();
    };
```

I am also setting a default message of "Loading..." if one isn't passed in.

---

**Edit:**

I could have sworn that worked for me in a past app I did, but judging by thr source, I think you are right, my answer above shouldn't work. My best suggestion is to add a class to the message element so you can target it, and use jQuery to change the text.

```
var _kendoApp;

var showLoading = function (message) {
    $(".loading-message").text(message ? message : "Loading...");
    _kendoApp.showLoading();
};

_kendoApp = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
    loading: '<h1 class="loading-message">Loading...</h1>'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, CodingWithSpike. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I always see the default message. I updated my question with version information, in case that might be relevant. Looking through the Kendo source it looks like it creates an element containing the text during construction and offers no way to change this after the fact. Any other ideas for things I should try?

Comment: Looks like you are right. Sorry, I actually had the above code in one of my apps and thought it worked, but I guess I didn't actually test it.  I edited my answer to add another possible solution.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that works. I had not thought of doing that. Much simpler than all the other routes I was pursuing! :-)